# Chrome remote desktop, Ubuntu 20.04, login to an existing session

Tags: google-chrome, remote-desktop

When I try to access my remote Ubuntu server via remotedesktop I'm presented with two login options,

- Default Launch the default XSession
- Ubuntu This session logs you into Ubuntu

The first option works provided that I am logged out of the remote system.
Option two does not work.  I cannot access a current session.

Is there anyway to access a current session?

Thanks